# Computation of Bessel-like integral

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions

I have to compute the following integral,
$$J(x;A,B)=\int_{0}^{x}dt\exp\left(-At-B\cos t\right),$$
where $B>0$ and $A>0$. Especially I am interested in $x=2\pi$ case. It seems that at least in this case this integral is something related to the Bessel function. However my attempts to find an appropriate integral representation were not successful. Can anyone help me with this integral?

Comment: Hi, this might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165832/integration-of-an-exponential-containing-trig-functions-over-a-finite-interval  I think that due to the linear term (multiplying A), in the end there's probably no closed form solution, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Also, this might help: https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9